# Yii how to detect transaction rollback in afterDelete() method

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, transactions

i'm trying to save any deleted row of a table in a different table in another database

so i override `afterDelete` method in `CActiveRecord`

like this

```
 if ($this->hasEventHandler('onAfterDelete')) {
            $this->onAfterDelete(new CEvent($this));
        }

    if(Yii::app()->user->isGuest)
       $user_id = 0 ;
    else
       $user_id = Yii::app()->user->id  ;
       // this is a method to save the row in different table  
    $this->setEventLog($user_id,"delete",$this->tableName(),$this->getAttributes());
```

this is work very fine for me except for one thing 
if the delete was in `transaction` and it `rollback`

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
$logtest = new mytable ;
$logtest->title = "title 2" ;
$logtest->save() ;

$logtest = new mytable ;
$logtest->title = "title 2" ;
$logtest->save() ;

$transaction->rollback();
```

it triggers the `afterDelete`  and save the row although it's not even deleted

how to detect the rollback in `afterDelete` method

Comment: The rolloback is done after the records is deleted so the afterDelete has already been called. So you can't detect a rollback in the afterDelete. You could override CDbTransaction and make the rollback action throw an event